# insufficient space for an object of type 'char' C and heap buffer overflow error

Tags: c, memory, malloc

i encounter this error when trying to run the following function in leetcode. but when ran on VSC with my own main function it works perfectly fine.

```
Line 15: Char 28: runtime error: store to address 0x602000000070 with insufficient space for an object of type 'char' [solution.c]
0x602000000070: note: pointer points here
 01 00 80 67  be 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
              ^
```

```
char * longestCommonPrefix(char ** strs, int strsSize)
{
    int z = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char* outputa = malloc(sizeof *outputa * z);
    for (i = 0; i < *strs[i]; i++)
    {
        for (z = 0; z < *strs[i*z]; z++)
        {
            if (strs[i+1][z] == strs[i][z] && strs[i+2][z] == strs[i][z])
            {
                outputa[z] = strs[i][z];
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    return outputa;
}
```

ive tried to implement a while loop to check if strs[i][z] != '0', but that just gets me a heap buffer overflow error. ive also tried rearranging how i wrote the malloc variable, with many people on stackoverflow giving different recommendations, all of which just land me on a heap buffer overflow error, or an insufficient space for type 'char' error.

Comment: Why `char* outputa = malloc(sizeof *outputa * z)` if `z == 0`?

Comment: Tip: `sizeof *outputa` is guaranteed to be `1`, so it's useless to multiply by this.

Comment: Re "*it works perfectly fine*", eh.... Can you truly ever claim that code that invokes undefined behaviour "works perfectly"? Even if it worked fine once, twice, or even a million times, it doesn't mean the next will work. And even the smallest change in completely unrelated code could change that.

Comment: i was using a different variation although i agree it doesnt make sense, my original value was, char* outputa = (char*)malloc((sizeof(char) * 200));

Comment: Again, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`. This makes even less sense.

Comment: why is it guaranteed to be 1? isnt that why we multiply by a certain value?

Comment: The size of `*outputa` is one as the size of `char, signed char, unsigned char` is _always_ 1.  If code later changed the type of `*outputa`, the size may change.  `malloc(sizeof *outputa * z)` is a good model to code as it is easier to review and maintain.  It is questionable why the allocation uses `z` and not something like `strsSize`.

Comment: @ Why is `longestCommonPrefix()` supposed to do with the argument `strsSize`?  Why was it there?

Comment: Leetcode uses their own main function to run the longestcommonprefix() function in which it gives a "strsSize" value, which i cannot change.